# Can chrome's network tab can be compared with jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, google-chrome-devtools

I have webportal for testing, our product owner want us to do measure performace of website by using chrome's network tab. Is it correct way to measure performance. My product owner wants me to mesaure Finish time and consider that time for performance of web portal. So my question is, is it a correct way of performance testing.[Chrome Network tab finish time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKShI.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tool reports **client-side** performance, you can rely on it up to certain extent as it reports how long did page load take from browser's perspective.

However the test is not very representative as for example I'm getting the page loaded in ~3 seconds (and I'm using flaky mobile internet) while you have ~13 seconds.

[image: JMeter Component Reference]

So I would recommend considering a better tool, for example [YSLow](http://yslow.org/) which not only measures rendering time but also can detect and report related issues.

Another point is, given application response time is 3 seconds while 1 user is accessing it, how do you know what response time will be when 100 users will be concurrently working with the application? 500 users? 1000 users? That's why you should not limit your performance testing to measuring DOM load and rendering speed only, you need to mimic at least anticipated number of your application users simultaneously accessing the application - this will give you some initial [performance metrics](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420665-Performance-Metrics-for-Websites) to see whether your application behaviour is acceptable or not.